# 'Cannot open program database' problem in Windows docker container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2015, ninja, windows-container

I use `ninja` as the build tool of `cmake`, `ninja` build parallelly. When build in the physical machine, it compiles without any problem, but in a Windows docker container, it reports:

> fatal error C1041: cannot open program database 'blabla.pdb'; if multiple CL.EXE write to
>   the same .PDB file, please use /FS

The compiler is MSVC 2015, but the `/FS` seems a 2012 or 2013 option, after add `/FS` to the CXX flags:

> The C++ compiler
>
> "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe"
>
> is not able to compile a simple test program.

It compiles without problem if I just use one core.

I have searched the web for a long time, but no useful information found.